# UITableViewController - Add Space above the Table / Move Table

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitableview

I need a free Area at the Top (above) of my grouped-style TableView in an UITableViewController. What's the Top? The Area between NavigationBar and SectionTitle of the TableView.

First, i used

```
UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 0, 0);
self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
```

That works fine in the first Moment, exactly what I need. But, if I scroll down the TableView, the view will move into the new free Area.

To work with

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

seems doesn't work :(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root view of a table view controller *is* the table view, so you can't put things above or below it, as there isn't a superview for you to add them to.

The solution is to use a UIViewController subclass instead, to this you can add a table view of any size, with views above and below it. There isn't much additional work involved - you have to declare that your view controller implements the delegate and datasource protocols, and connect those outlets up in IB, aside from that it's the same as a table view controller.

Basic message - you can have a table view without a UITableViewController.

Comment: +1 This will work great, and is the way to do it.  The only potential issue is that this won't work if it is a static table view, in which case it has to be in a `UITableViewController` and not a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: You said the same class twice but I get what you mean. I was looking at another question which made me wonder if you did have to have static tables in a UITableViewController to get them to work, have you actually tried this then?

Comment: Yeah, I meant UIViewController for the second one, and yes.  Using a static table view in a UIViewController results in a runtime exception which says that they MUST be in a UITableViewController.

Comment: Saves me testing that myself, cheers! I guess you could do it with view controller containment, which is another option here.

Comment: Thanks - that was the way I went. UIViewController (with protocols from tableViewController) -> UIView (for free-Space) | UITableView -> connect delegate and dataSource - works!

Answer (score 2):

If your table is read only, jrturton suffices. Otherwise, you also need to propagate the editing call from the UIViewController to the enclosed UITableView as follows:

```
//In UIViewControler propagate call to tableView property
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
  [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];  
  [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the headerView property of table create one view with required size and put it in the header view of table it will give you what you exactly  need.

You can use `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate method of tableView to put the header view for first section.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank you for your reply! It doesn't work. It's exactly the same; if I scroll up/down, the ContentArea appears over the "freeSection".

Answer (score 0):

So you need a space above the Table view, which doesn't get covered by the table view when it is scrolled?

Instead of playing around with the table view, just try to add a `UILabel` on top of the table view or in place where the header of table view would have been there. Then make the table view's co-ordinates start right below that of the label. This way when you scroll, the space, i.e; the label here, is always visible.

The reason to do this is because everything defined for a `UITableView`, such as the header or footer, is always associated with the table, and cannot be manipulated separately.